# Populate not populating, only ID's are showing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a User Schema and a Task Schema, which are linked to each other.
When creating a new task, the correct User ID gets stored in the "author" field.

This task that was recently created, I push into the Users "tasks" array, to store the individual tasks referenced by their ID.

When running populate after this, nothing happens. At the moment, the "tasks" array is just an array of IDS, instead of an array with the content from the actual tasks.

Am i missing something?

Thank you for your time

User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate( value ) {
            if ( !validator.isEmail( value ) ) {
                throw new Error( "Email is unvalid" );
            }
        }
    },
    tasks: [ {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Task"
    } ],
    tokens: [ {
        token: {
            type: String
        }
    } ]
} );

const User = mongoose.model( "User", UserSchema, "users" );

module.exports = User;
```

Task Schema

```
const TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
} );

const Task = mongoose.model( "Task", TaskSchema, "tasks" );

module.exports = Task;
```

Creation of new Task

```
router.post( "/api/tasks", auth, async ( req, res ) => {
    const task = await new Task( {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        author: req.user._id
    } );

    req.user.tasks.push( task );
    req.user.save();

    task.save( ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
            throw new Error( error );
        }
        if ( !error ) {
            User.findOne( { email: req.user.email } ).populate( "tasks" ).exec( ( error, tasks ) => {
                if ( error ) {
                    throw new Error( error );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
    res.send( task );
} );
```

The output of this is just an array inside the user documents that contain the ids of the tasks, and not the actual data of the task (such as name, description etc)

What i want is that the user has its "tasks" array, and inside that array, is the individual task with the correct data, such as task name, task description etc.

Comment: you have initialize the tasks field as a reference field so it will only store the ids and refer to the tasks collection. if you want to save the tasks content initialize it as an Array field Ex: tasks : {type: Array}

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but all the other tutorials with populate have shown to do type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Objectid and that still works.